# javascript declare multidimensional array with specified indices

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

I want to create a multidimensional array that will eventually look like this:

```
s
    [4]
        [3]
            [7][235,25903,502935],
            [8][2973,20385,97250],
            [9][293,2752,2935]
        [4]
            [7][28357,2057,923705],
            [8][2398,20597,20579],
            [9][275,23975,203795]
```

In PHP this is very easy to do, but in javascript I keep getting some BS about the 2nd dimension being undefined:

```
var s = [];
    s[4][3][7] = [23095,20753,2067];
    s[4][3][8] = [2664,86295,29357];
```

(that is not how I would do this in PHP btw)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to declare each nested array as an `Array` before you can assign values to it:

```
var s = [];
s[4] = [];
s[4][3] = [];
s[4][3][7] = [23095,20753,2067];
s[4][3][8] = [2664,86295,29357];
```

Comment: You should note that iterating over this array may not be straightforward.

Comment: I assumed that the OP wasn't concerned about iterating over it, since the question title explicitly states that he wants "specific indices."

Comment: @Travesty: Ugh! I was afraid of that. what BS… Thanks!

Comment: Oh, ignore this comment—firebug just displayed it as `[undefined,undefined[undefined]…]` but when I fully expanded `s` everything was there. Thanks!